# Tensorflow: TypeError with numpy_input_fn

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, typeerror

I am coding a Convolutional Neural Network to classify images in TensorFlow but there is a problem:

When I try to feed my NumPy array of flattened  images (3 channels with RGB values from 0 to 255) to a tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn I get the following error:

```
  TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'dict'> to Tensor. 
  Contents: {'x': <tf.Tensor 'random_shuffle_queue_DequeueMany:1' shape=(8, 
  196608) dtype=uint8>}. Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

My numpy_imput_fn looks like this:

```
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={'x': train_x},
    y=train_y,
    batch_size=8,
    num_epochs=None,
    shuffle=True)
```

In the documentation for the function it is said that x should be a dict of NumPy array:

> x: dict of numpy array object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, for those having the same problem I fixed it. In my model function i had:

```
input_layer = tf.reshape(features, [-1, 256, 256, 1])
```

Which raised the type error. To fix it you have to access the 'x' key in the features dictionary:

```
input_layer = tf.reshape(features['x'], [-1, 256, 256, 1])
```